Should one avoid making a negative double with a weak four card major?
Both vulnerable at matchpoints, I dealt and bid one spade with a J-high suit and a 13-count.
Left hand opponent overcalled two diamonds.
Partner made a negative double with the following: ♠AK ♥9843 ♦84 ♣K9543, signaling strength in the "round" suits. This put me in a spot, because I had ♠J8754 ♥AT7 ♦KQ ♣QJT.
In a previous discussion on this question, the point was made that the main point of making a negative double was to find a 4-4 major suit fit. But here, there was no such fit to be found, and even if you made my heart holding AT72, the combined "eight card" holding would have been AT987432.
Can it be right to try for such a fit with an honorless four card holding? Partner did have 10 high card points but 70% of them were in his spade suit. With AK of partner's five card suit, I would have raised that suit, even though it would only be a seven card fit. Would that have been a better idea? The combined spade holding would have been AKJ8754, much better than the actual combined heart holding of AT98743.

Negative double here doesn't show the rounded suits. In modern bidding, it only shows the unbid major(s). The only time it shows 2 suits is when the bid suits are both majors or both minors.

Decades ago, I read a newspaper bridge column that has stayed with me through today.
It was a hand where they found a 4-4 spade fit and ended up in 4♠, which would have made 4 on good play.
Why do I mention this?  Because "good play" was simply "pull trump, losing 3 tricks to the ♠AKQJT that broke 3-2, get the tenth trick by ruffing.  Oh, 3NT goes down because the trick ruffed would have gone along with 2 more in that suit."  At the table (according to the story), declarer panicked, didn't pull trump, and went down, losing the three trumps they were going to lose and a ruff.
Why does it stick with me?  Because every couple of months, I'm in a contract where everything works except the horrible trump suit.  Sometimes it's 4-x and  I go down; sometimes they get their ruff before I get to pull all the trump and I go down; but frequently "all I lose is 3 trump tricks".
So, yes, we should be looking for a 4-4 heart fit; even if partner also doesn't have any trump honours, it is frequently the only making game (and more frequently, the best making partscore with no game on - "they don't find the trump lead off the top, I crossruff 6 tricks and two Aces before they get back in, +110").
If it doesn't happen, like here, sure maybe the 5-2 plays better than the 4-3, but:

Maybe you get two spade ruffs with your small trump, or "pull trump" by threatening the ruff, and end up establishing either black suit.
Maybe they bid 3♦ with their 9 card fit, and play the misfit instead.
Maybe, when your partner bids 2♠ instead of doubling, they bid 3♦ on the 9-card fit:

so, do you take the push?
Would you have wanted to if partner was 3=5=2=3 with the same honours?
If so, how do you guess right?




Yes, 100% right to look for the H fit. (Even if opponents had all the H honours 2H is still first choice with a 4-4 fit. In H you should have 2 spare trumps to stop opponents running diamonds, and only 1 spare trump in S)
If opener doesn’t rebid H, responder can comfortably raise opener’s 2S, pass 2NT, or support 3C.
It’s difficult for opener, who’s forced to rebid a poor hand without a natural rebid, but they made the choice to open so must see it through.
